# Quadratic equations. Get a b c

Tags: javascript

Hey guys. I want to make a program that can solve Quadratic equations like:
0 = ax^2+bx+c. I can solve it using the variables a, b, c. The problem is that you manually have to pick out a, b and c. Is there any way of getting the variables from a equation like this? 0 = 5x^2 + 4x + 3
Here we would get
    a = 5
    b = 4
    c = 3

I'm doing it in javascript btw.
I hope you can help me

Comment: If you're only looking for that exact notation, you could use a simple regular expression…

Comment: Depends on how well you know the input format. Is it always in the `"0 = ax^2+bx+c"` structure, or may the two `=` operands be switched? What about switching the terms (e.g. `c+ax^2+bx`)? What about whitespace?

Comment: Include in your answer what you have tried so far, so that we can see that you have at least tried.

Comment: Will the variable always be `x`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the split method could work for you here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp
First split the string on "+"
Then split each of those strings on "x"
then grab the first element of the three arrays.

This assumes that every function added is of the same format. You'd have to turn all minus signs into plus signs (by making the multiplier negative), or check to split on minus signs as well.

Comment: NOOOO no no no no! Don't reference W3Schools ***ever***

Comment: A better reference for the same function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: `split` is kind of inappropriate for the second part. Just use `parse(Int|Float)`…

Answer (score 0):

This should be more than enough to get you going; some assembly required.

Do you know if the Y value will always be on the left?  Whether you'll ever see the form  `Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0` may add a step or two; I'll assume Y will always be on the left.

1. I would start by removing all white-space from the string.

   - `quadratic = quadratic.replace(/ /g,'');`
2. Then split the string by `=` and work with the right side.
3. Extract your variables (while preserving negatives).

   - ```
     var A = quad.match(/([-]?\d+)(?=[a-zA-Z]\^2)/);
     quadratic = quadratic.match(/-?\d+[a-zA-Z]\^2/,'');

     var B = quadratic.match(/-?\d+(?![a-zA-Z]\^)(?=[a-zA-Z])/);
     quadratic = quadratic.replace(/-?\d+[a-zA-Z]/,'');

     var C = quadratic.match(/-?\d+/);
     ```
4. Plug that into (-B ±√(B<sup>2</sup> - 4AC))/2a and test the results

   - You obviously have to do two separate functions as there is no ± operator.
   - Hint: *squared* is `Math.pow(x,2)` and *square root* is `Math.pow(x,.5)` or `Math.sqrt(x)`.
   - Remember that if the discriminate is >0 there are two real solutions, =0 there is one real solution, or <0 there are no real solutions (but two complex solutions).